# How to get back the data when the key is a number ? - Firebase - Vue.js

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I want to know if data exists for the date selected by the user. The data is sorted by year and month.

I put them in base like this:

```
    saveUserToUsersRef(user){
      let year = {};
      let month = this.months[0].selectedOption;

      year[this.years[0].selectedOption + "/" + month] = {
        'data' : 'xxx'
      }

      this.currentDate = year
      return this.usersRef.child(user.uid).update(year)
    },
```

I can not recover them as I recover other data :

```
{{currentUser.firstname}} // Denis
```

But when I make `{{currentUser.2018}}` I have an error because of the number.

How to recover the data in the key 2018?

How to recover data dynamically by replacing 2018 with a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it with square braces and apply it as a string.

`{{currentUser["2018"]}}`

You could replace `"2018"` with any variable also:

`$year = 2018;`
`{{currentUser[$year]}}`

## Edit

You can get the current year or month using PHP's date function like so:

```
echo date('Y'); // 2018 (year)
echo date('n'); // 05 (month, may)
```

So for example:
`$year = date('Y');`
`{{currentUser[$year]}}`

See the full list of formats from the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: it works thanks to you. One last thing how can I dynamically added the month ?

Comment: Can you post an example of your `currentUser` object please? It's hard to tell the structure based on what you have shown. Are you trying to dynamically add the current year and month? ie. May 2018

Comment: currentUser return this: `{ "email": "test@gmail.com", "firstname": "Denis", "entreprise": "Entreprise", "lastname": "Test", "manager": "Responsable" } ` There are other data but I do not use them. My code is JavaScript not PHP.